# Como resolver esse erro no Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e peguei esse erro ao pegar uma nova versão dele no `github`, após o inicio o servidor não consigo executar a aplicação, aparece esse erro:

> `No Application Encryption Key Has Been Specified`

Comment: [`php artisan key:generate`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrompa o servidor dando um <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> e digite:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Depois só dá `start` no servidor novamente.